# Display static content with specific extension as html

Tags: nginx

I am running as a static file server using nginx.  I have a file with a specific extension i.e. *.diff. Right now Nginx serves it as `text/plain`. I want this specific extension to be served as HTML. I added below which works. Wanted to understand if it is right.

```
location ~ (\.diff$|\.ext1$) {
            default_type text/html;
        }
```

Just wanted to confirm, if this is right way to handle this.

Comment: About professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration

This question is more likely to get an answer on Server Fault.

Comment: @Hacker Disadvantage of your approach (besides being workable) is that you can't use it if you'd need to serve those files via some other special location along with the files of other types. However since `default_types` directive doesn't accept variable as its parameter, the only alternative I can see is to edit global `mime.types` file, which isn't a good idea (that file can be overwritten during nginx upgrade, etc.)

Comment: If i have to edit mime.types what should add in it?